# android - Replay of OverlayItem on Mapview in realtime

Tags: android, sqlite, android-mapview, osmdroid, android-overlay

I'm using OSmdroid to display numerous `ItemizedOverlay` in realtime (from network). How can I replay back and forth the laid overlay item? For example may be with a scroll bar or similar component, I should be able to replay the whole display items until the latest item.

My idea as of now is write the data received onto SQLite DB and read whenever the scroll is activated. But I also know that simultaneous read and write on SQLite is not possible. So, how can I at the same time read & write from DB? Or Is this a good approach to proceed or is there a better way to display history data of `ItemizedOverlay`?